# Waking up with Galaxy Gear

Tags: alarm, vibration, clock, samsung-galaxy-gear

I bought GG partly to wake up in the morning (Like with a Fitbit), but so far I have either woken others or I have not woken up.

IS there a good hybrid solutions, like some "Phoene only apps".

I would like an increasing "disturbance", like first only wibrating gear.  Later attamps should start with the same, but move to more effects, from both Gear and Phone.

Also important is that one of the devices go off if the other is out of battery (or in a mode where it doesn't do anything)

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Is it just me or does this feel like a feature request?

Comment: A solution perhaps?  (Sometimes on these exchanges it is illegal to ask certain questions)